# Working with bitmask in C and rewrite it into Python 3.6

Tags: python, c, bit-manipulation

I have a simple code in C-language:

```
/* Bad if it's missing any of the "good" bits */
if ( (f & det->mask_good)
       != det->mask_good ) {...};

/* Bad if it has any of the "bad" bits. */
if ( f & det->mask_bad ) {...};
```

where f is a constant like "0xfeff".

I have to use the same condition in Python 3.6 and I did the following:

```
bitwise_bad = np.bitwise_and(MaskData[i,], f)


condition_good = bitwise_bad != MaskData[i,]
condition_bad = bitwise_bad

join_condition = np.logical_or(condition_good, condition_bad)
```

I don't have any problem with code, but I am not sure that I rewrite these lines correctrly, because I am not familiar with C-language at all.

I'll be very thankful if you say where I am wrong.

Comment: I don't know python, but it seems to me that the C code is less than ideal... keeping the masks as part of the object seems wasteful in most situations (especially when the same amount of data is likely to cost 3 bits instead of 16 bytes)...

Comment: yep, but it is a mask for each image, and it is from hdf5 file, so as I got it is impossible to avoid such things)

Comment: I am not python expert (far from it) but as long as I know, python supports the bitwise operations like `&`, `|` and so on. So why not `bitwise_bad = MaskData[i,] & f`?

Comment: @AlexLop, & and | are the same as np.bitwise_and/or. There are no difference.

Comment: @kitsune_breeze Anyway the code doesn't seem to be the same. In C, for "good" case `mask_good` is used and for "bad" case `mask_bad` is used. In the python code all the logic is based on the same mask.